# Javascript library for exporting XML

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-serialization, couchdb

I'm currently using couchdb to store documents as JSON.  One of my clients needs to grab XML (for now).  Anyone know any good javascript libraries that can take a javascript object (or json string) and export valid xml?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

json2xml.js: http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/